# How to invert the scrolling axis from Y to X on JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a horizontal scrolling website where I want to take the users' Y-scrolling input to convert it into X-scrolling. The website already works perfectly when using a trackpad and scrolling on the X axis, so I just want it to work the other way around. Thanks!

This is what I'm trying to workshop but I'm very new to this and it's probably *very* wrong:

```
 <script>
        let invertedscroll = window.ScrollY;
            
        window.addEventListener('scroll', (scrollY) );
        
        function invertscroll (scrollY) {
            window.scrollY = window.scrollX;
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to set `scrollLeft` directly to the `<html>` when scrolling using the `wheel` event.
And don't forget to call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent vertical scroll

```js
document.documentElement.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault() // prevent vertical scroll
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft += event.deltaY
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
section {
  height: 150px;
  min-width: 50vw;
  background: blue;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

**UPDATE**

There is a conflict in your example, but the reason is `scroll-snap-type` property, which controls your scroll behavior with css. I don't think it is suitable for horizontal scroll. Also combination of CSS and JS solutions for controlling a scroll would be glitchy. So the best approach would be to use only JS here.

It can be tricky to keep your `scroll-snap` behavior with all its benefits and the best approach would be to use some slider library. There are many such libraries, but you need to search a bit to find a suitable solution.

If you want to implement this behavior by yourself, you can start with something like that. But current example works only for mouse wheel and it needs a lot of improvements.

I use `scrollTo` for horizontal scroll, passing `slideIndex` multiplied by `slide width`. Then I set `isScrolling` to prevent scroll until `smooth` scroll is finished. And in the `requestAnimationFrame` method I check current scroll until it finishes and reset `isScrolling` to allow next scroll

```js
const scrollableContainer = document.getElementById("slider")

let slideIndex = 0
let lastSlideIndex = 5
let isScrolling = false

let expectedScrollLeft = 0

const checkScrollEnd = () => {
  // check if current scroll is finished
  if (scrollableContainer.scrollLeft !== expectedScrollLeft) {
    // if the scroll is not finished, run function again recursively
    window.requestAnimationFrame(checkScrollEnd)
  } else {
    // otherwise set isScrolling and allow next scroll to fire
    isScrolling = false
  }
}


scrollableContainer.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  
  // do nothing until the previous scroll has finished
  if (isScrolling) return

  // check scroll direction and find next slide index
  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    ++slideIndex
  } else {
    --slideIndex
  }
  
  // some cecks to avoid setting slideIndex less than 0 or more than slides count
  if (slideIndex > lastSlideIndex) {
    slideIndex = lastSlideIndex
    return
  }
  if (slideIndex < 0) {
    slideIndex = 0
    return
  }

  // set isScrolling to prevent excess triggering
  isScrolling = true
  
  // expectedScrollLeftis used to check when current scrolling is finished
    expectedScrollLeft = slideIndex * window.innerWidth

  scrollableContainer.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: slideIndex * window.innerWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  })
  
  // requestAnimationFrame is checking for scroll ending of every frame
  window.requestAnimationFrame(checkScrollEnd)
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#slider {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slide {
  height: 150px;
  min-width: 100vw;
  background: blue;
}

.slide:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! This works like a charm. Unfortunately, it seems to be at conflict with a different segment of the code: 'overflow-x' on the css. [Here's a screencap](https://imgur.com/a/LBwkkJI).

The website is meant to be a single row where every 'slide' (100% viewport), snaps to center. Overflow makes it so that when you start scrolling, the motion doesn't stop until you snap onto the next slide. But when left on the code, the scrolling doesn't work! Turning it off means no snapping, though 

Comment: Yes, there is a conflict in your example, but the reason is scroll-snap-type property, which controls your scroll behavior with css. I don't think it is suitable for horizontal scroll. Also combination of CSS and JS solutions for controlling a scroll would be glitchy. So the best approach would be to use only JS here. I also added a solution that you can start with if you want to implement this behavior by yourself, but keep it mind, that it still needs a lot of improvements)

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time :-) I'm only getting started with JS so I still have a lot to learn, but I'll definitely revisit this once I'm more versed in the language and see if I can figure out an implementation.

Comment: Yes, this seemingly simple task is actually quite tricky) Follow common practices in the beginning of study, it is easier to implement and this experience will be more useful. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) and invertScroll instead of "scrollY" which is undefined in your implementation:

```html
<script>
    window.addEventListener('scroll', invertScroll);

    function invertScroll(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      window.scrollTo(window.scrollY, 0);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Won't you need to access the `event` argument of the handler and call `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Just tested it out in repl.it, you are correct!